# Dynamic font sizing?

Tags: css

Is it possible to adjust the size of the font, depending on the length of the word?

I have a situation where I need to display one word, on one line. But the word can vary between 1 and 10 characters long. I would like the text to be a maximum font-size of 65px, but adjust the more characters are added so that when all 10 are used, the word doesn't get pushed out of view.

The dimensions are always going to be fixed (portrait iPod), just the length of the word is variable.

Any CSS ninjas out there mind teaching an old dog a new trick :)

Comment: CSS is not a programming language. It doesn't care about your content.

Comment: you'd be able to in javascript. But not css

Comment: Not all letters are the same width (III vs MMM); are you using a monospace font?

Comment: Font is not monospace. I think it's likely going to be a case of best-guessing it client side. Not a problem as I first started down that path (a little overhead sure).

Comment: Smth like that can be achieved by SVG + CSS: http://codepen.io/yoksel/full/XJbzrO/

Comment: no css but js approach would work. something like: http://jsfiddle.net/kz6jc90q/

Answer (score -4, accepted):

you can use javascript to change font-size according to string length -

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var n = str.length;
if(n>10){
document.getElementById("id").style.font = "italic bold 20px arial,serif";
}
```

hope this help..

Comment: Yeah, already headed down that path before thinking about a CSS alternative. Have an accept anyways!

Comment: `.style.font-size` is invalid.

Comment: The catch is the character length doesn't have a lot to do with the actual length rendered as characters are different widths (usually).